# PHPStorm + Gulp. Autorun default?

Tags: phpstorm, gulp

I rely on Gulp to do loads in my project, even syncing files with the server because PHPStorm took ages to detect changes made by Gulp.
I keep forgetting to run my watcher function on start up - it's annoying.

Is there any way I can auto run a gulp task on PHPStorm start up?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instruction here: 
 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/using-gulp-task-runner.html